# Can we set the order of the nodes in one layer by edges using dot to draw a tree diagram?

Tags: dot

How to set the order of the nodes in one layer by the order of the definition of edges rather than the definition of nodes when using dot to draw a tree diagram?

For example,
For some reasons i need to first define node1, node2, and node3,
and then draw the edges: node3 -> node2, and node3 -> node1,
and i hope that the edges are drawn as they are defined.

below are the .dot files

```
digraph G {
    node1 [label = 1];
    node2 [label = 2];
    node3 [label = 3];
    node3 -> node2;
    node3 -> node1;
}
```

[image: fig 1. node2 on the right]

but I want it to be like this:

[image: fig 2. node2 on the left]

How can I realize this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9167887/13785815. Short answer: add line `ordering=out;` after the first line.